# Windows authentication - testing for different users

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

My application does not have any roles.
However I use windows authentication to stop anonymous users from accessing the webpages.
I need to test different users using the system.
I do not want to know different users passwords and I cannot set up dummy users in Active Directory.
So how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Set up a virtual server with Active Directory Domain Services and IIS on it. Build yourself a domain for your testing and create your dummy users there. Then you can put your ASP.NET application on it and test your app using the different users, but it'll be completely sandboxed from your live Active Directory setup.

Comment: That looks like the right answer, but I need permission to set that up which I will not get.

Comment: Are you blocked from running Virtual PC on your development machine? That and a Windows Server DVD are really all you need.